# How can I indent multiple lines in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, code-formatting

When I select multiple lines of code and want to indent them as usual with <kbd>TAB</kbd> key, it just deletes them all. I come from Eclipse where I always did it that way. How's that done in Xcode? I hope not line by line ;)

Comment: I wish the Tab key did this in Xcode.

Comment: Anyone know if you can remap the tab key to this behaviour?

Comment: It's funny because I'm pretty sure I was able to use Tab for right indent before. It just one day stopped working...

Answer (score 937, accepted):

The keyboard shortcuts are <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> for indent and <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> for un-indent.

- In Xcode's preferences window, click the Key Bindings toolbar button. The Key Bindings section is where you customize keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: Note that these are commonly used Mac OS X key bindings thus you can indent using CMD-] and CMD-[ in, for example, Mail.app.

Comment: Some apps that also run on other OSs use TAB and SHIFT+TAB instead, like eclipse and any derivatives

Comment: Additionally, Ctrl + I reindents your entire code in the active editor based on your text-editing preferences in Xcode.

Comment: Thanks for that tip - I didn't know that.  Frustratingly, on German keyboards, there is no [ or ] key - so to indent, you actually have to hold CMD+ALT+6 to indent.  God, I miss Visual Studio sometimes...

Comment: French keyboards should be the worse I think: ctrl+alt+shift+')'. Four stupid keys to indent a few lines. That's just as bad as it can be.

Comment: Haha, with a Swiss (FR-CH or DE-CH) keyboard it is Cmd+Shift+Alt+6, and 5 to unindent... could not be worse.

Comment: I am going to abandon XCode as soon as Appcode gets its act together with Swift. For people who have not used IntelliJ IDEs, I feel very sorry!

Comment: Swedish: CMD+ALT+8 and CMD+ALT+9

Comment: Coming from windows into os x I wish I would had known this days ago.

Comment: Intuitive. Not.

Comment: @FredrikJohansson I was just thinking that this is (almost) a universal code editor shortcuts standard. 800+ points just for answering this question!? o_O Fair enough.

Answer (score 66):

Select your code to reindent, then Go to

> Editor -> Structure -> Re-Indent

Comment: -1: The question was how to indent a block of lines, not on how to have it indented automatically by XCode. IMHO, this is a big difference.

Comment: not the correct answer, but it's a useful reminder anyway!

Comment: Don't forget to '⌘ + A' before doing it

Answer (score 48):

<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd> and <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd> are the equivalents to <kbd>shift+tab</kbd> in Xcode.

Comment: It does apply to multiple lines if you have multiple lines selected at the time.

Answer (score 39):

Here are the shortcuts, to format the code in XCode

1. **Format entire code (entire class/controller)**

   Select the entire code and **press <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>  on mac** to format your code.
2. **Format particular block of code**

   Select the code and press:

   - <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> for right move (indent)
   - <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> for left move (un-indent)

Note: as per @JavierGiovannini sugesstion you can do using Editor Menu option

3. **Select your code and navigate to *Editor > Structure > Re-Indent***

Comment: 1. It should be Ctrl + I

Comment: It is ctrl + i !!! The letters l (lowercase L) and I (uppercase i) look equal! Please use lowercase. I'm unable to edit this post due to SO's inexplicable 6-chars restriction.

Answer (score 21):

First, select all code using `command`+`a`

Second, hold key `ctr` and then press `i`

the whole selected code will nicely indent.

Answer (score 17):

**Multiline Indentation** Shortcut key:

> **ctrl + i**

NOTE: Please select *codes* to Re-indent and press 'control' and 'i' on your mac.

Answer (score 12):

Another way to quickly reformat indenting is a quick cut and paste. <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> and <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>. I often find it faster than <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> or <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> as you can do it with one hand (versus two) and it will reformat to the correct indent level in one shot.

Comment: IMO, you should compare it to `⌘`+`I` which "has it indented automatically by XCode", not just "indent a block of lines".

Comment: This also works for us that does not work on an american keyboard :)

Answer (score 10):

If you use synergy (to share one keyboard for two PCs) and PC(MAC) in which you are using xcode is slave, and master PC is Windows PC

keyboard shortcuts are <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> for indent and <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> for un-indent.

**Update:**

But from synergy version 1.5 working <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> for indent and <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> for un-indent

Answer (score 7):

In Xcode 9, you can finally use Tab and Shift+Tab to indent multiple lines of code. Yay!

Answer (score 4):

Select "Tab key: Indents always" in Preferences->Text Editing->Indentation
Then you can indent a single line or a selection of lines by pressing <kbd>TAB</kbd> or <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd>
Sadly this removes altogether the possibility to insert tabs where you want, and conflict badly with the tab key being used to switch between "autocompletion fields".

I guess we need more tab keys in the keyboard, one is not enough...

Answer (score 2):

To all frenchs Xcoders around, the default keybindings are as follow :

#### Indent selection:

<kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>)</kbd>

#### Unindent selection:

<kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>(</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

For those of you with **Spanish keyboard** on mac this are the shortcuts:

<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd> for un-indent

<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd> for indent

Answer (score 2):

For code indentation first select the lines of code then press:

**command + alt + [**

**command + alt + ]**

Answer (score 2):

Select the lines and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> from keyboard.

You will have the lines indented.

Answer (score 1):

here all the important shortcuts from another question answered on stack overflow
[image: here]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remap the standard Xcode's <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> to <kbd>TAB</kbd>, you can do the following:

1. Install a program called "Karabiner".
2. Go to Preferences ~> "Misc and Uninstall"
3. In "Custom Setting" section click on the "Open private.xml" button
4. Open the file and replace its content with the following code:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?> 
   <root>
       <item>
           <name>Tab instead of Command+[</name>
           <identifier>private.swap_tab_and_cmnd+[</identifier>
           <autogen>
               __KeyToKey__
               KeyCode::TAB, ModifierFlag::NONE,
               KeyCode::BRACKET_RIGHT, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L | ModifierFlag::NONE
           </autogen>
       </item> 
   </root>
   ```
5. Go to Preferences ~> "Change Key" ~> click on "Reload XML" button
6. Put a tick in the checkbox which is called "Tab instead of Command+["
7. Enjoy

[image]

PS: Please note that this setting works globally on your machine, not just in Xcode. However, I am sure that google might help you to find a solution how to customize it even further, applying the changes only to Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

**Danish Keyboard**

Unindent: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⌥</kbd> + 8

Indent: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⌥</kbd> + 9

Answer (score 1):

Basically <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>[</kbd> for left multiple indent and <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>]</kbd> right multiple indent.

For `TR` keyboard you can left multiple indent with <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>⎇</kbd> <kbd>8</kbd> and right multiple indent with <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>⎇</kbd> <kbd>9</kbd>.Because both <kbd>8</kbd> and <kbd>9</kbd> are `ALT` characters of the these nums.Or if you have a keyboard which has <kbd>[</kbd> or <kbd>]</kbd> characters are belong to `ALT`(<kbd>⎇</kbd>) property so you can use <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>⎇</kbd> <kbd>KEYBOARD CHARACTER</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Since I didn't see an update to this question for the current version of Xcode, I thought I'd add that in Xcode 9.3, Tab works for indenting selected line(s) of text as well as moving from one autocomplete field to another.

Answer (score -1):

In Xcode 4.2 auto-indenting is pretty good. You can now indent a selection of code by pressing the Tab key. I find that Xcode generally formats code really well automatically, and you rarely have to move things around yourself. I find it faster to select a piece of code, right-click and choose Structure -> Re-indent if some code looks messy.

Comment: i think you have not used any other code editor except xcode in your life. xCode autoCodeFormatting is the worst.

Comment: Doesn't work in XCode 8.3. Don't know if it ever did.

Answer (score -1):

Tab for Indent 
SHIFT + Tab Re-indent