# Fix code indentation in Xcode

Tags: xcode

Once I start editing my code and adding for loops or if then statements my code indentation is whacked because the previous code maintains its former indentation instead of adjusting automatically.

In Visual Studio you can highlight code and select 'format selection' to fix these issues - is there anything similar in Xcode?

Comment: [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/829954/how-can-i-indent-multiple-lines-in-xcode) is the best solution

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode source automatic formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1573968/xcode-source-automatic-formatting)

Answer (score 260, accepted):

Before Xcode 9 (for Xcode 9 see default shortcut below)

1. select text
2. right-click
3. there's a "Re-indent selection" item in popup menu

---

In XCode 4 there is one more step:

1. select text
2. right-click
3. Click on "Structure"
4. there's a "Re-indent selection" and other options in popup menu

---

Or using the default shortcut:

1. select text
2. press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd>

Comment: This apparently doesn't work with ObjC++ in Xcode 5, the "Re-indent selection" option simply does nothing

Comment: As of Xcode 9 the right-click option is no longer present. ctrl + i does still work though.

Comment: ctrl + i ... Thats it

Comment: LOL I misread and tried command + i, and it rebuilt my project and asked me to select a profiling template.

Comment: `ctrl` + `i` it is indeed, I was confused whether it "i" or "I" or "|", it is plain "i", thanks

Answer (score 83):

1. select text
2. press `Control-I` (the default keyboard shortcut)

Comment: Spent too much time hanging out in other IDEs lately and my brain thought this was worth erasing.

Comment: Control-I does nothing for me as of XCode 11.  Is there really no menu option for this at all?

Comment: @PaulSlocum Control-I still works for me in Xcode 11. It's also in the menu in Editor > Structure > Re-Indent.

Comment: lol, been trying the IntelliJ shortcut coming back to Xcode long time later.

Answer (score 26):

You can do this automatically in **Xcode 11**

[image]

Comment: this is GENIUS! Thank you!

Answer (score 17):

In Xcode 4.6.3, choose `Editor` > `Structure` > `Re-Indent`.

Shortcut: `Control + I`
(that's 'i', for 'indent')

This works on current selection. If no text selected, choose `Edit` > `Select All` (⌘+A) and then perform the re-indent.

(I'm more clearly restating the other answers)

Answer (score 7):

Sometimes [setting Xcode global preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59855756) is not enough for `^` + `i` to do its job accordingly. The reason is that project settings override global ones. You can set indentations for a concrete project or even a file.
Select project (or file) in the `Navigation Pane`. Then in `File Inspector` go to `Text Settings` section and set desired number of tabs or spaces for indents.

Comment: This answer has screenshots of where to find these settings: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47023275/59913

Comment: This allowed me to track down why Xcode was indenting using _3_ spaces when it is configured globally for 4.

Answer (score 6):

These solutions re-indent text to the default xCode behaviors. To change these behaviors, go to xCode (v.4) > Preferences > Text Editing. Then to Indentation Tab.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for... and yet not... I was hoping I could tell Xcode to do things like indent private: and public: inside of a C++ class... instead it aligns them underneath the class keyword, but I see no such option.

Answer (score 6):

**Xcode 9.2:**

You can select text and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd> to re-indent code.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it in different ways, but these two are the easiest

- **select text** ( <kbd>⌘</kbd> +<kbd>a</kbd>) :

1. Using shortcut -> **(control)<kbd>^</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd>**
2. Click on **"Editor"** -> Click on **"Structure"** -> Click on **"Re-indent"**

Answer (score 4):

To quickly re-indent the whole file:

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>

**Edit**: No longer working in Xcode 11

Comment: Is this any different to cmd + a, ctrl + i?

Comment: It will work after @tetrajen solution: Xcode Preference > Text Editing > Indentation > mark the "Re-Indent on paste".

Answer (score 2):

You can try my extension Swimat
https://github.com/Jintin/Swimat

It support format on selection.

Simple install by `brew cask install swimat`